# Binding Issue with SelectList in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm facing an issue with binding a SelectList in my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I have a form where I need to populate a dropdown list with order IDs, but I'm encountering a RuntimeBinderException that states: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Count'.

I've tried various solutions mentioned online, including converting the SelectList to IEnumerable and using the Count() method, but I'm still encountering this error.

Here's a simplified version of my controller code:

```
// GET: Items/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var itemsWithOrders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
    var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
    {
        OrderID = item.OrderID,
    }).ToList();
    ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID");
    return View();
}

// POST: Items/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([Bind("ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock, OrderID")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _itemsService.CreateItem(item);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    var itemsWithOrders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
    var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
    {
        OrderID = item.OrderID,
    }).ToList();
    ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID");
    return View(item);
}
```

Code for a Dropdown list in the Create view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID, "Select Order", htmlAttributes: new { @class =` "control-label"})

@if ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList != null && ViewBag.OrderIDList.Count() > 0)
{

    @Html.DropDownList("OrderID", ViewBag.OrderIDList as SelectList, "-- Select an Order --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
}
else
{
    <p>No orders available.</p>
}

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

How can I resolve the RuntimeBinderException related to the SelectList not containing a definition for 'Count'?
Is there an alternative approach to binding a dropdown list in ASP.NET Core MVC?
I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

**Update**!
I am getting the below error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download your sample and change the connection string to my local DB, then, there is an error in the `20230903113035_SeedData.cs` file, the Orders table doesn't have [the "ItemName" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQm6O.png).

[image]

After removing this `ItemName` column and then generate the related table and seed data, if I run the application, the dropdownlist contains options, liek this:

[image]

Then, if you change the code to `ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID");`, the output like this.

[image]

You can check your code again.

**Update:**

> Did you try creating an item to see the error message that pops up?

I reproduced the problem using your code, the output as below:

[image]

The issue relates the code in the post method, when create the SelectList the `orderIDs` doesn't contains the `Order` property.

> ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "Order",
> item.OrderID);

You should change it to:

```
 ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID", item.OrderID);
```

The whole code of the Get and Post method as below:

```
    // GET: Items/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var itemsWithOrders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
        var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
        {
            item.OrderID,
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Items/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([Bind("ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock,OrderID")] Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _itemsService.CreateItem(item);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        var itemsWithOrders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
        var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
        {
            OrderID = item.OrderID,
        }).ToList();

        if (orderIDs.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID", item.OrderID);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.OrderIDList = null;
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

The output as below: after creating a new Item, the DropDownList still work well.

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating an item to see the error message that pops up?

Comment: @Blessing, the issue related the code (`ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "Order", item.OrderID);`) in the HttpPost method, when create the SelectList the orderIDs doesn't contains the `Order` property. So, you should change the code to `ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID", item.OrderID);`. More detail information, refer the update in the above reply.

Comment: I see I am no longer getting that error now. I just need to check why the Item is not getting created when I click create

Comment: Do you know how I can sort out the issue? I am not getting any exception errors now but when I click on 'Create' nothing happens.

Comment: @Blessing, if you set a break point in the Create Post method, you can find the ModelState.IsValid is `false`, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVLpd.png), the issue relates the Order Property in the Item class. To solve this issue, you can create a ItemViewModel, which contains the bind properties, and in the Create Post method, use the ItemViewModel to receive the data, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQhPe.png). Then, the new item can be adding success, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8M1L.png).

Comment: @Blessing, Since the original question has already solved, you can close it and accept the answer, if you have any further question, it is better to create a new question, then it is easier to us to see the new question and help you. Thanks for your understanding. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML

Replace this

```
@if ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList != null && ViewBag.OrderIDList.Count() > 0)
{

    @Html.DropDownList("OrderID", ViewBag.OrderIDList as SelectList, "-- Select an Order --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
}
```

with this

```
@if (ViewBag.OrderIDList != null && ViewBag.OrderIDList.Count() > 0)
{    
    @Html.DropDownList(m => m.OrderID, ViewBag.OrderIDList as SelectList, "-- Select an Order --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
}
```

You need to provide the selector variable which in this case is OrderID from your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
@if((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList != null && ViewBag.OrderIDList.Count() > 0)
```

Try using

```
@if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.OrderIDList) > 0)
```

Comment: I am getting 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
'. I tried checking for null but it is giving the above error

Comment: That means OrderIDList is null, try null checking before checking the count

Comment: I did that inside my if statement in the view

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as below:

Action methods:

```
        var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
        {
            OrderID = item.OrderID,
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID");
```

View Page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID, "Select Order", htmlAttributes: new { @class ="control-label"})

    @if ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList != null && ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList).Count() > 0)
    {

        @Html.DropDownList("OrderID", ViewBag.OrderIDList as SelectList, "-- Select an Order --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No orders available.</p>
    }

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Then the output as below:

[image]

Besides, you can also use the [select tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-select-tag-helper) to display the dropdownlist, it also gets the same result, code like this:

```
       <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID, "Select Order", htmlAttributes: new { @class ="control-label"})

            @if ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList != null && ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderIDList).Count() > 0)
            {
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="OrderID" asp-items="@ViewBag.OrderIDList as SelectList">
                    <option value="0">-- Select an Order --</option>
                </select> 
            }
            else
            {
                <p>No orders available.</p>
            }

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the first code snippet for the GET or POST?

Comment: It is used in both the Get and Post methods.

Comment: I am getting the same error again. It's pointing to the conditional statement in the view.

Comment: Please check the screenshot I've added at the bottom of the post

Comment: @Blessing, when you meet this error? After the page load or after clicking the Save/Edit button? You can try to set a break point in the Action method (Get and Post) to check the ViewBag.OrderIDList value, whether the items contain the relates values? Like this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNxAv.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNxAv.png). Besides, you can try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on), or add some test data like I did in my sample and then test it again, if still not working, can you create a minimal, complete sample to reproduce the problem and share the project to us?

Comment: it shows up after clicking on 'Create Item'. I added a break point in the Action method (GET) and there are OrderIDs similar to the snapshot you provided. The POST request is not getting executed because this error pops up as soon as I click create. I can give you the link to my repo to have a look at this project and run it? Would that be fine?

Comment: @Blessing, "I can give you the link to my repo to have a look at this project and run it? Would that be fine?" Okay, you can share the link to the repository, but be careful to hide sensitive information in the repository. Then, I will check it.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/Bless-Siba/OrderEase-Final Check the Create for Items and Orders are both not working.

Comment: @Blessing, please check my new reply, it contains your project test result.